# How to use another query in an IN statement?

Tags: sql, db2

I have these query:

```
 Select CODE
 FROM TABLE.STATUS
 WHERE REFERENCE IN ('423',{variable})

Select Sec_Code
From Table.Sec_status
Where Sec_reference = 'ABC'
```

The second query returns 35 triple digit codes that I want to insert into the {variable} sections I tried :

```
 Select CODE
 FROM TABLE.STATUS
 WHERE REFERENCE IN ('423',(Select Sec_Code
 From Table.Sec_status
 Where Sec_reference = 'ABC'))
```

But that errored out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to combine any hard-coded numbers into the subquery. Try this:

```
 Select CODE
 FROM TABLE.STATUS
 WHERE REFERENCE IN (
   Select Sec_Code
   From Table.Sec_status
   Where Sec_reference = 'ABC'
   UNION '423'
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't combine a value list and a sub query in an in clause.

You'll need to either use an `OR`

```
WHERE REFERENCE = `423` or 
      REFERENCE IN (Select Sec_Code
                From Table.Sec_status
                Where Sec_reference = 'ABC')
```

or use a single SELECT that unions your sub query and static value

```
WHERE REFERENCE IN (Select Sec_Code 
 From Table.Sec_status
 Where Sec_reference = 'ABC'
UNION ALL
Select '423' 
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
```